# Is it possible to populate an array of data from using dropdown list value in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel

Here is my problem:

I have a worksheet dedicated to a raw data-set in columns A:C. The data-set consists of amounts, dates (mm/yyyy), and a status.

Within the same worksheet I have dedicated arrays that count the specific amounts for each month of the year and sort out the status' from my raw data set.  In total, I have 24 arrays dedicated to displaying two years of data.

Using the name manager I've named my arrays by their corresponding month.

What I'd like to do is populate one array at a time when called upon by a list drop-down value (the mm/yyyy) on a different worksheet. Is this possible?

I've experimented with VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try advanced filter.
       Sub Adv_Filter()
Range("A1:C56").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
Range("F1:F2"), Unique:=False
End Sub

Here F1:F2 is the dates with drop down.
[Sample Adv Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe5NO.jpg)
You have to take the complete data set to another sheet. You can even try by simply recording the macro.

Happy to Help. Tell me if further assistance required.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try!